# Navigation Bar covers other elements

Tags: html, css

today i have following problem i have responsive navigation Bar that covers my website logo
[image]

In that case i cant click on my logo i mean i cant use `<a href ....`. Here is .mean-bar css

```
.mean-container .mean-bar {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: 0 0;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    z-index: 999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
    height: 55px;
}
```

I tried to add margin-left but i lost responsive.
I want to reduce size (width) of my mean-bar without lose resposive
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Please add more code + html

Comment: A quick way is to set `z-index` of logo to a value more than `.menu-bar` z-index.But i would suggest to use flex to handle  the layout instead of `absoulte` positioning.

Comment: @AbbasEbadian ye but then my menu (☰) stop working

Comment: Then You should set menu width to `calc(100% - [logo-width]px)`.OR  remove `width=100%` and add `right:0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find out the logo div **class or id** and apply the CSS below

```
.logo-class {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9990;
}
```

replace `logo-class` with your class

Comment: Thanks for answer.Forst i added only z-index and it not workbut after edit wtih     `position: relative;` it works.Have a ncie day!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your .mean-bar has z-index: 999, your logo should have z-index: 1000.

If it doesn't work might be good to share a link to the site you're working on.

**Update**, add this in your CSS:

```
.main-responsive-nav .logo {
z-index: 1000;
max-width: 200px; }
```

".main-responsive-nav" class should be added so that it will only affect the .logo class when viewing in mobile.

Comment: ye but in that way my hamburger menu stop working. [link](https://carhunt.bg/) to my website

Comment: ".main-responsive-nav" where should i added it?And after add "max-width: 200px;" - again not working

Comment: ".main-responsive-nav" should be added as parent class of ".logo". Therefore we have ".main-responsive-nav .logo". You can copy the CSS code I gave to your style.css or in your Admin Dashboard > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS

Comment: Thanks for answer.Found a solution i should add    ` position: relative;` to .logo class